# N asset portfolio volatility with equal volatilities and correlations

Tags: correlation, variance

I'm reading this book, "Unperturbed by volatility", by Adel Osseiran and Florent Segonne and it says the following:

> Then, if we assume that individual volatilities (sigma) and correlations (rho) are the same for all assets (and pairs), then the volatility of a portfolio N equally weighted assets is
>
> sigma_N = sigma * SQRT(1/N + (N-1)/N * rho)
>
> We see immediately that the limit of the benefit is sigma_N = sigma * SQRT(rho) when N is large. This represents the limit where idiosyncratic risk is removed by having more assets, and when correlation is high there is no benefit.
>
> It can be surprising to see SQRT(rho) a square root, as it clearly requires the average correlation to be positive. This is a property of the average correlation: the average correlation rho_N for N assets verifies rho_N >= - 1 / (N-1).

I don't understand how this means that rho in the square root is always nonnegative since for every N >= 2 it holds that - 1 / (N - 1) < 0?